# can we map json response to python object similar to Object mapper in Jackson?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to map json response to python object in similar way like we do in Java using jackson library so that we can work with Java object.

sample json:-

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age": 31,
    "city": "New York"
}
```

Class to Map these parameters

```
class PersonDetails:
    name: str
    age: int
    city: str

    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int, city: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.city = city
        
     def get_age(self):
        return self.age
        
     def set_age(self, age):
        self.age = age
        
     def get_name(self):
        return self.name
        
     def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

     def get_city(self):
        return self.city
        
     def set_city(self, city):
        self.city = city
```

and wanted to map json with this personDetails class.

Below code is written to parse json and i am getting values in jsonConverted variable but i want to use **PersonDetails** class so that i can fetch values with getters and setters similar way like we do in Java using jackson library.

```
responseData= json.dumps(response.json())
jsonConverted= json.loads(responseData, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
print(jsonConverted.name, jsonConverted.age, jsonConverted.city)
```

is it possible to do that ?

Comment: `PersonDetails(**json.loads(responseData))`? Btw, you really should look into python properties rather than manually setting your own getters and setters.

Comment: `**` unpacks a python `dict` to keyword arguments. So `json = {"name": "John", "age":  31, "city": "New York"}` and then `PersonDetails(**json)` translates roughly to `PersonDetails(name="John", age=31, city="New York")`.

Answer (score -1):

A code below which does object mapping.

```
import requests
import json

class CreateObject:
    def __init__(self, d=None):
        if d is not None:
            for key, value in d.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)
   
def deserialize_response2(api_url):
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    data = json.loads(response.text)   
    responseObject = CreateObject(data)
    users = [CreateObject(field) for field in responseObject.data]
    responseObject.data = users
    return responseObject

result_object = deserialize_response2("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
print(result_object.data[0].email)
```

There is another approach using Marshmallow framework. If you want to try check my blog post https://xeon2k.wordpress.com/2023/12/26/marshmallow-a-python-orm/